# What substances found in a medieval town could be used for chemical warfare?

Tags: warfare, medieval, chemistry, siege

There is a small medieval town under siege by a much larger force. The town militia stands no chance at repelling the invading army, but the besiegers are in no rush to conquer the place. Instead of storming the town, they've decided to set up a perimeter and choke it - cutting the townspeople off from all supplies and waiting until they crack.

During this siege, one cunning townsfolk decides to take matters into their own hands. They decide to fight back with a bit of subterfuge, sabotage, and a lot of toxic substances.

This person sneaks into the invading army by pretending to be a sympathizer. They then plant several casks of chemicals, they poison several officers meals, they set chemical fires, etc. They use as much hazardous, toxic or poisonous substances as they can find from the town.

The question: how much is that, and what sort of dangerous chemicals would actually be available in a fairly rural, medieval town?

It can only be stuff that is readily available or salvageable in the setting - they can't go mining or importing from afar. The town could contain any stores that are reasonable - such as tannery, a brewery, an inn, etc. There could be an apothecary, but it wouldn't be a particularly exotic one (think medieval England).

They could extract or distil chemicals using any resource that it is present (it's a slow siege, they have time to prepare).

The ideal chemical would be something that could kill a lot of people, and also potent enough that a single person could reasonably transport and plant it. Ideally, it would also be something fairly obscure/specialised, to explain why no one else has thought of using it before.

Edit: Assume that the saboteur is especially advanced for his time, so using any chemistry or knowledge above what existed in medieval times is fine.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105300/discussion-on-question-by-archtea-what-substances-found-in-a-medieval-town-could).

Answer (score 5):

Look at the traditional set of defensive means used in those times:

- poisoning the wells was an often used approach: before retiring into the walls under a siege, any water source/storage would be polluted, by either dropping some poison or some pollutant (a rotting corpse or dung, for example)
- one can cook certain stones to make lime (CaO). It reacts with water and it's pretty nasty.
- tar and oils, if warmed up, can do some damage on the poor folks being showered with them.
- in lucky and limited cases you might have someone able to make vitriol (diluted sulfuric acid)
- corpses, though they work better in an enclosed environment. If thrown on the sieging force, they can easily dispose of them. If thrown in the sieged city they are more likely to spread an infection.

Answer (score 3):

As a saboteur, especially one working alone there are 2 ways of affectively damaging an opposing army.

One is aiming high in the hierarchy and taking out commanding officers whose death or sickness/absence could be a blow for the siege/battle. 
But that doesn't apply THAT much in your situation, since it is and already long established siege, and that doesn't need as much command, as it needs large amounts of people to man the perimeter 24/7. Taking out 5 or 10 of the commanding officers, could strike fear, but not really affect the outcome, since they have enough men. But you could do it while the hero is brought to an officers meeting since he is considered a traitor and he could have valuable info. But also it wouldn't be realistic if more than a few low level officers deal with a traitor that could easily be a double agent. They wouldn't just bring him in front of the General with enough time to poison him.

The second (and in my opinion much more effective way) would be to target the main population with something that affects all of them. You should have the guy either target food storages and either poison them with death-cap mushrooms or maybe not enough for killing but making people sick with belladonna.
Most effective would be poisoning the water supplies, and that usually is done by dropping corpses in the water source (your hero could  kill a couple of dogs or other animals and drop them in wells). 
This way it affects not only humans, but animals like horses that could be crucial for carrying heavy siege equipment. It could be also not so easily noticed if it was a well or a stream next to the stables that only horses drink from, and since it was noticed too late it had a devastating impact when the majority of animals turn sick or dead.
Another less realistic but more "chemical" way would be acquiring a good amount of quicklime and creating one or many slow bombs. Either by covering the quicklime with something that slowly dissolves in water and when the quicklime core is revealed it would explode. Your hero could throw this in a water well next to the barracks or command-tent. 
Or simply hang them by a slow burning rope in the well and when the quicklime drops in the water it would make the explosion. Technically though the reaction between water and quicklime produces CO2 and not exactly explosion, but in the confined space of a well you could say that the gas was too quickly generated and it did an explosion. As i said not TOO realistic but i would call it acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

[Methanol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methanol#History) - distilled from/by wood pyrolysis. Just "fortify" some barrels of wine or whiskey or whateves and let them capture the load.

Answer (score 1):

**Hellebore.**

[image]

[A History of the Materia Medica, John Hill 1751](https://books.google.com/books?id=enWnuv3r08MC&pg=PA561&dq=hellebore&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjE1ezih4HoAhWJY98KHU4FCDsQ6AEwA3oECAAQAg#v=onepage&q=hellebore&f=false)

Hellebore is a pretty flower and can be a weed.  It has been used for medical purposes since ancient times because it is powerfully toxic.  Old herbals like Culpepper and Hill clearly show the respect these folks had for hellebore.  It has also been used as a pesticide which I found interesting; apparently this use is seeing a renaissance because it is easy to grow and easy on the environment / beneficial insects.  I could imagine a medieval apothecary might have a large stash of this stuff both more medicinal uses and in anticipation of treating plants with it.

Hellebore also is famous for being the original chemical warfare agent.

https://antiquitynow.org/2013/11/14/chemical-warfare-in-the-ancient-world/

> The poisoning of the water supply was another method of chemical
>   warfare that was used in the classical world. During the First Sacred
>   War, 595-585 BCE, when the city of Cirrha was being besieged, the
>   water supply was cut and when the defenders were suffering from
>   thirst, the water was turned back on with the added bonus of hellebore
>   roots, which poisoned the supply. This had the effect of rendering the
>   defenders defenceless and allowed the city to be taken.

Your double agent can poison the wine.  The people besieging the city will get sick.  They might not know they had been poisoned; people get sick.  It is not easy to besiege a city - you have to count on your friends to resupply you and you are out there in crappy tents.

I could imagine that the best defense is a good offense and when those besieging the city are good and sick, the town militia comes out and brings the fight to them.